# Multi steps Dropbox logic in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, scripting

I hope you and your families are well.
I need your guidance on a small issue which I am facing, I have been trying to find/do the solution for the past 3 days and couldn't find it.

I am using a simple React library for the below.

**Scenario**
I have created 4 dropboxes,

1. IDdropbox = it contains, some numbers, and this id is enabled when the webapp load, and rest all are disabled. When anyone clicked and choose ID, it enable the second dropdown menu FruitList
2. Fruitlist - the options here are populated depending on the ID chosen before, and enable the thirst dropdown menu
3. extraFlavor = it will contain some extra flavour option, and this list is populated by the previous option (FruitList)
4. recepieMenu = it enable by previous action, and it shows the options set my extra flavour

**Working**
For example

1. If user selected 2 in the first dropdown
2. then the second dropdown should show "Orange, Banana, Apple"
3. If use choose Orange, then the third dropdown should show "Vanilla","strawberry" etc
4. One user select Vanilla, then the 4th dropdown should show something like "Valline Apple Shake, "Vanilla Apple Ice Cream" etc

**Issue**
Now the issue is, I can use Dropdown1, that' is not an issue, but I am not able to populate data in the rest of the dropdowns. I tried using ReactHooks, userState, useEffect, and they are not working for me.

I know, I might be doing something stupid, but I couldn't find out where is issue lies.

Thanks for reading this question and thanks for your time.

Regards
Aman

[image: Choose the fruis]

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
const ChooseTheFruit = () => {

```
function CreateOptions(props) {
    let data = Array.from(props.data)
    return (data.map((item, index) => <option key={index} >{item}</option>)
    )
}

const [idNumber, setIdNumber] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const [fruitList, setFruitList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    setFruitList(fruitList)
}, [fruitList])

//functions
const populateFruits = (e) => {
    const currentID = e.target.value
    console.log(currentID);
    setIdNumber(currentID);

    switch (currentID) {

        case 1:
            setFruitList("Orange,Pineapple");
            break;
        case 2:
            setFruitList("Kiwi,Banana");
            break;
        case 3:
            setFruitList("Almonda,Pistachu");
            break;
        case 4:
            setFruitList("Papaya,Mango");
            break;
        case 5:
            setFruitList("Muskmelon,Watermalon");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    console.log(fruitList)

}

//rendering
return (
    <>
        <div>
            <h3>Please choose the Fruit</h3>
            <br />
            <select id={"myNumber"}
                onChange={populateFruits}
            >
                <CreateOptions data={idNumber} />
            </select>
            <br />
            <select id={"fruitList"} > <CreateOptions data={fruitList} /></select>
            <br />
            <select id={"extraFavourMenu"} ></select>
            <br />
            <select id={"recepieMenu"} ></select>
            <br />
            <button>Fetch Receipe</button>
        </div>
        <div id="receipe" >here we will show recepie contents</div>
    </>
);
}
export default ChooseTheFruit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you pass a string to `setFruitList`, also inside the `populateFruits` function you change `setIdNumber` which is the list of the first select, and the `useEffect` has dependence with `fruitList` and inside it set `setFruitList` which can make infinite loop.

I fixed these issues, please check.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-colden-kx9lqx

Comment: Hello @Mina, first, thanks for taking the time and thanks for answering my question.  Thanks, for fixing the code and put the code on codepan. I checked the code, and if you don't mind, few line I am not able to understand,  like `setFruitList((prev) => {
      console.log(prev);
      return prev;
    });` l, what this code is doing, are we replacing the previous values? , second, 'const populateFruits = (e) => {
    const currentID = e.target.value;
    setIdNumber(+currentID);
    console.log(+currentID)
  };' why we used +CurrentID? whereas our variable name is 'currentID'

Comment: Also, to populate other two dropboxes, do i need to follow the same code in the useEffect? Thanks again for your help...

Comment: @AmanDhally, You are welcome, for the points you mentioned, the first point, this code doesn't affect anything, I just want to see the latest value for the `fruitList` state, you can delete it and it will not affect the functionality,

Comment: For the second point, `+` is converting string to number, `event.target.value` will be a string value, Ex: '1', '2', I need these values in number format, like 1, 2, because in your `switch` statement you compare with numbers.

Comment: `Also, to populate other two dropboxes, do i need to follow the same code in the useEffect?`   Yes, use the same approach I made to continue with other selects.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mina for the help and the pointers, and YES, i have managed to do the rest of the code., it's time for me to learn more about UseEffects :(